# Replace value in dataframe column until specific conditionally changing value is reached

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df which looks like this:

```
data = [["nota", "b"], ["notb", "nota"], ["a", "b"], ["a", "notb"], ["notb", "notb"],[ "nota", "notb"], ["nota", "nota"], ["notb", "a"], ["b", "notb"], ["b", "a"], ["nota", "nota"], [ "notb", "b"]]


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["status1", "status2"])
```

Output looks like:

```
status1   status2
 nota       b
 notb      nota
  a         b
  a        notb
 notb      notb
 nota      notb
 nota      nota
 notb       a
  b        notb
  b         a
 nota      nota
 notb       b
```

What I would like to do is to iterate through each of the columns seperately (from top to bottom) and replace values (or delete them if that makes it easier) based on some conditions.
Starting in the first row, I want to replace all values in the respective column with "empty" until it says a or b. The cells could also be replaced with anything else or get deleted if this makes the whole thing easier since I'm not interested in the altered cells anymore as long as they are not either "a", "b", "nota" or "notb".
Then I would like to replace all values with "empty" until nota is reached (in case the first column which was not replaced was "a"). If the first not replaced cell said "b", I want to replace all cells until there is a "notb". After that I want to repeat the process and replace every cell in the respective column until "a" or "b" is reached again, and so on.

Desired output would look like this:

```
 status1   status2
 empty       b
 empty      empty
  a         empty
 empty      notb
 empty      empty
 nota       empty
 empty      empty
 empty       a
  b         empty
 empty      empty
 empty      nota
 notb        b
```

Please note that I have several other columns that I don't want to treat like those.
It is important that it is not possible that there is a "b" after an "a" without an "nota" between them and vice versa.

Thank you very much in advance if anyone could help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
def process_status(x):
    out, cur, cur_end = [], None, None
    for v in x:
        if cur is None and v in {"a", "b"}:
            cur, cur_end = v, {"a": "nota", "b": "notb"}[v]
            out.append(v)
        elif cur_end == v:
            cur, cur_end = None, None
            out.append(v)
        else:
            out.append("Empty")
    return out


df["status1"] = process_status(df["status1"])
df["status2"] = process_status(df["status2"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   status1 status2
0    Empty       b
1    Empty   Empty
2        a   Empty
3    Empty    notb
4    Empty   Empty
5     nota   Empty
6    Empty   Empty
7    Empty       a
8        b   Empty
9    Empty   Empty
10   Empty    nota
11    notb       b
```